# How to update a cell's value according to colored cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

In a Google Sheets spreadsheet, I have some cells green and red-colored. I want a cell having the count of those green/red colored cells.

Is there a formula to do this thing or any custom code for this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to could access the cell's color, but if the color is somehow related to the cell contents, I'm sure you could write a formula and/or script to do it.

Is there any relationship between a cell's color and its contents?

Comment: Color is not related to content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions?hl=es) should get you started (see [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmR0r1Y14zgydG03QS1Dd0dLRDA3SWgtLXp6TzV3d3c#gid=7)):

```
function countRedBackgrounds() {
  var COUNT_RED = 0;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cell colors");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  for (var i = 1; i<dataRange.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j<dataRange.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      if (dataRange.getCell(i,j).getBackground() == "#ff0000")
        COUNT_RED++;
    }
  }
  dataRange.getCell(1,1).setValue(COUNT_RED);
}
```